# Wrap table row to the next line

Tags: html, css

```html
<table id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <td>testtesttesttest</td>
    <td>testtesttesttest</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like that if the table does not fit on the screen, then to the second cell of the table will be transferred to another row down? Not the text in the cell, but the whole cell.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792728/use-jquery-to-move-columns-in-order-to-next-tr-when-page-is-resized)

Comment: @eggy Definitely not. Not everything is jQuery.

Comment: @Keelan Now, everything is media queries.

Comment: @lolzerywowzery seems quite an overkill for something that can be solved with `inline-block`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Change the cells to inline blocks:

```css
#table_id {
  display: block;
}

#table_id td {
  display: inline-block;
}

td {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<table id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <td>testtesttesttest</td>
    <td>testtesttesttest</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjbyE/)

Comment: You are a CSS god!! Every other answer claims it's impossible, but this worked. My situation was such that I couldn't change the table to divs since it was being generated by a plugin I do not author.

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to "wrap" entire columns, i.e. when a cell wraps in one row, to wrap the same cell in other rows as well?

Comment: @rustyx: (a bit late perhaps, but) what works for me, is setting a width on the table cells (in em-units so that it scales with user zooming).

Comment: This wraps the long rows, but not the short rows, so the columns don't line up properly. In particular, if you have a row of column headings, they don't line up with the data columns below them.

Comment: It is essential that you add vertical-align:top} otherwise you will not simulate td as the vertical alignment will be out. the answer by niet shows how to do this without table tags but the vertical align is still important for alteration of td tags from table-cell to inline-block or block (if breaking to rows).

Comment: `table` is `display: table;`, so if you put `display: block;` then this question or answer are misleading as that is not a `table` anymore, just a normal `div` and therefore nothing special or problem solving.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with a table, the "row and column" grid is fixed.

However you could use `inline-block` elements:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>testtesttesttest</div>
    <div>testtesttesttest</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#container>div {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improved upon [Jukka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17159819/2392683).

HTML:

```
<table id="table_id">
<tr>
<td> testtesttesttest</td>
<td> testtesttesttest </td>
<td> testtesttesttest </td>
<td> testtesttesttest </td>
<td> testtesttesttest </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> testtesttesttest</td>
<td> testtesttesttest</td>
<td> testtesttesttest</td>
<td> testtesttesttest</td>
<td> testtesttesttest</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#table_id  {display: block; }
#table_id  td {display: inline-block; border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;}
td { background: green;
     border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;} /* to show cell sizes */
```

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/zjbyE/391

Comment: This is great, except for one thing.  Each row seems to have its own width now.   A 6 column thead `<th>`  does not display the same width as 6 column `<td>` in the rows below.  I am needing very similar to above, but if Row 5, needs to wrap  6 columns to: four columns line 1, two columns line 2, then I need all other rows to do the same regardless of the size of the content in each row.