# How to split Gridview rows into two in Yii2?

Tags: gridview, yii2

Here i like to explain my problem clearly

i have gridview like this
[image: Gridview]

> Here i want to print my father_name , father_dob etc into next like
>   the given image below.

after the field of mobile everyone as to print in next line,

how can i do this
like this image below

[image: gridview2]

How can i do this in yii2 Gridview

Comment: As it is a table maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17159819/57091

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` has an `afterRow` attribute that you can use. Do it like so:

```php
<?= GridView::widget([
    ... //your parameters here
    'afterRow' => function($model, $key, $index) {
        return Html::tag('tr',
            Html::tag('td', $model->father_name)
            .Html::tag('td', $model->father_dob)
            //add more columns
        );
    }
]);
```

So `afterRow` should return a `tr` tag that will be appended to the body right after the `tr` tag that is rendered by `GridView`'s `renderTableRow`.