# Is there any way to make a <td> take up a full row on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a form that has a very simple layout:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

On a desktop, I would like it to have 4 columns, each 25%. When it gets down to a mobile, I want the first td to be on its own row and be 100% width, then below that the other three are 33% wide.

I can't get this to work with "width" colspan="3". It just pushes the whole table to be wider than the container. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you share your CSS too? Or better yet put this into an example at jsfiddle.net and share that?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17159819/2557128) suggests using `display:inline-block` CSS?

Comment: You could set different display for the table elements https://jsfiddle.net/jfkwxhnz/ if you want to use `33%` for the cells then you need to make sure there are no white space between those `td`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrap table row to the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159708/wrap-table-row-to-the-next-line)

Comment: It looks like whatever is stopping it from working is css from bootstrap. The posted jfiddle works when it's isolated.