# Is there a way to break table rows in pairs using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Imagine you have a table that has two rows. But for some reason you cannot know what will be the size of the container, and you want it to break. Yet, it is crucial that odd and even rows stick together. In other words, instead of getting this:
[image: Undesired Row Break]
I want to get this:
[image: Desired Row Break]

Is it possible to achieve that effect with CSS?

Comment: This will entirely against the concept of table structure. I think you can make the table responsive to avoid such kind of discomfort.

Comment: @Ratheesh no responsive trick I know works to get that, apart from maybe reordering elements for different viewports, but that seems cumbersome — especially with lots of dynamically generated content.

Comment: If you have lots of dynamic content it will be cumbersome. In your server side/client side code you can keep the data for next broken row and add it in the next iteration. Still it is not a good method.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to do this! The recipe is very simple:

1. You need to apply the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159708/wrap-table-row-to-the-next-line/40525531#40525531) to change the `table` display property to `block`, and `inline-block` for `td` elements.
2. For each vertical pair of words you make a row. In each row you put a table, which has 2 rows and 1 cell in each. The upper word goes to the upper row cell, and the other one goes to the bottom row cell.

Resize the window to see how the table wraps itself.

```css
#wrappable {
  display: block;
}
#wrappable td {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table id="wrappable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>Column 1 – upper row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Column 1 – bottom row</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>Column 2 – upper row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Column 2 – bottom row</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>Column 3 – upper row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Column 3 – bottom row</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>Column 4 – upper row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Column 4 – bottom row</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>Column 5 – upper row</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Column 5 – bottom row</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Boom! It's done! and it works perfectly in Firefox 64.0.2 even with transitions done on that table.

Comment: Can you please show how this transforms (with an exact example) the above image 1 into image 2 **by using pure CSS**?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Why pure CSS? I just wanted to achieve that without chaging the logical structure of table for each container width. I have achieved that with pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: Your answer in this state has nothing to do with the above (your) question.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I don't understand. It does exactly what the question solicited.