# How to wrap and center elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page, where I am showing 10 small (~100x200 pixels) images evenly spaced at the bottom of the page.

```
|                                                                                     |    
|                   The page when wide enough                                         |    
|                                                                                     |    
|                                                                                     |    
|                                                                                     |    
|   +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+    |
|   |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |    |
|   |  1 |  |  2 |  |  3 |  |  4 |  |  5 |  |  6 |  |  7 |  |  8 |  |  9 |  | 10 |    |
|   |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |    |
|   +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+    |
|                                                                                     |    
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like the images to automatically wrap and center, if the browser window is narrower.

```
|                                                                                     |    
|                   The page when more narrow                                         |    
|                                                                                     |    
|                                                                                     |    
|                                                                                     |    
|                +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+                       |
|                |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |                       |
|                |  1 |  |  2 |  |  3 |  |  4 |  |  5 |  |  6 |                       |
|                |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |                       |
|                +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+                       |
|                                                                                     |    
|                        +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+                               |    
|                        |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |                               |    
|                        |  7 |  |  8 |  |  9 |  | 10 |                               |    
|                        |    |  |    |  |    |  |    |                               |    
|                        +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+                               |    
|                                                                                     |    
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried many different things with table, div and both combined.
But I can't seem to get this exact bahaviour.

Anyone got any good ideas?

The page has php, but I have tried solving this with HTML and CSS (but with no luck)

Comment: Please provide your `HTML` and `CSS` or, better, a [mcve].

Comment: "I have tried many different things", please include your best attempt, and describe what else you've tried so far.

Comment: Well, all of my attempts are scraped again ;-/

I also looked at this, but it didn't do the trick:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159708/wrap-table-row-to-the-next-line

You can see the images at the bottom of this page:
https://www.astronet.dk/

Comment: That's what medaiqueries (or container queries) are for. What did you try, how did you try and solve this with CSS?

Comment: @RudiBjørnRasmussen Kindly, add your attempt to the question and not as an external link.

Comment: Only use a table to display tabular data. If it's about images you use HTML + CSS for that. Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code,Althoguh it would have been better if you gave us an example

```
.container:{
display:flex;
align-items:"center";
justify-content:"space-evenly";
width:100vw;
flex-wrap: wrap;
overflow:auto;
}

image:{
width:150px
height:150px
}
```

Comment: Sorry - no resizing issues regarding the above. This is caused by other elements on the page.

Comment: Okay...cool you can accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: ah o now I get it. Just flagged your answer as "accepted". Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Create a container wrapping your images. Apply `display: flex` and  `justify-content: center` to always center your images to the center of the container. Then, to take care of overflowing, apply `flex-wrap: wrap`. This way, the images overflowing the container will wrap into a new line.

```css
.robot {
  width: 150px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
  <img src="https://ps.w.org/shortpixel-image-optimiser/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1038819" class="robot">
</div>
```

If you want to create a gap on a smaller screen like the example you gave, you can create a media query taking care of the container's width.
In the media query, we are going to change both the width (to make the container smaller) and the margin to center your container:

```css
.robot {
  width: 150px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/ChenBri/pen/XWqBgoG)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. I added css that louis suggested.

```
   .robot {
  width: 150px;
  Padding: 5px;  
  }

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And then added a little more to add some spacing (padding) arround images and vertical align.

All there's missing now, is that the layout will follow resizing the window.
Especially when resizing the window to be more narrow. But that's not so important.

Thanks again all!

Comment: I posted an answer, including the resizing you desired. Please take a look. It also looks like your CSS is a copy of what I posted. Getting a simple response could be nice. Especially if you want more help in the future.

Comment: Well, thanks ChenBr - I sure hope that you haven't excluded me from any future help on stack overflow 

Comment: It's all good, I just wanted to make sure you saw my post. I wanted to let you know because you're a new contributor to the site :)