# How to break long rows in HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

A similar question has been asked before here: [Wrap table row to the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159708/wrap-table-row-to-the-next-line), but with no satisfactory answer.

I need to have a HTML table that wraps long rows to a new line while maintaining the alignment of each column and column heads, i. e. the table should display normally as long as the total length of a row does not exceed the available horizontal space. If this space is exceeded each row should be broken in two or more lines as shown in the diagram below.

[image: desired behaviour]

The number of columns is dynamic as the user can select the columns to be shown.

While the accepted answer in the above question does indeed wraps long rows to a new line it breaks the vertical alignment of columns.

The closest to what I need is the solution in the above question:

```css
#table_id {
  display: block;
}

#table_id td,
#table_id th {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table id="table_id">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Vorname </th>
      <th> Nachname </th>
      <th> Klasse </th>
      <th> Weitere Vornamen </th>
      <th> m/w </th>
      <th> Mobil </th>
      <th> Telefon </th>
      <th> Adresse </th>
      <th> PLZ </th>
      <th> Ort </th>
      <th> SF </th>
      <th> EF </th>
      <th> S3 </th>
      <th> KU </th>
      <th> KU+ </th>
      <th> P5 </th>
      <th> LS </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Dummy </td>
      <td> Student </td>
      <td> 23PA </td>
      <td> One </td>
      <td> w </td>
      <td> 0123 456 789 </td>
      <td> 012 999 99 99 </td>
      <td> Streetaddress 11 </td>
      <td> 1111 </td>
      <td> City </td>
      <td> PAM </td>
      <td> PH </td>
      <td> E </td>
      <td> BG </td>
      <td> MU </td>
      <td> S3 </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Another </td>
      <td> Student </td>
      <td> 23PA </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> m </td>
      <td> 0123 456 789 </td>
      <td> 012 999 99 99 </td>
      <td> Hauptstrasse 100 </td>
      <td> 2222 </td>
      <td> Other City </td>
      <td> PAM </td>
      <td> WR </td>
      <td> E </td>
      <td> BG </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> EF </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

While this wraps the table rows as needed the columns are no longer aligned.

[image: current behaviour]

The table is dynamically generated from a database query and the user can select the columns to display.

Also I could think of using CSS grid system to program a solution but unfortunately I need to export the resulting table to PDF via the Weasyprint library - which doesn't support CSS grids (for the time being, at least).

Comment: Personally I'd do display: flex in this scenario, and remove the default table styling for this purpose.